# Passing a class object into an array of class objects in VB6

Tags: arrays, class, object, vb6

So I have a question which seemed simple at first but is quickly becoming confusing.

I have a class object, lets call it customer, which has 2 variables, firstName and secondName.

I then want to pass this object into an array of the same object, lets call it arryCustomers.

So when I call arryCustomers(0) I want to pass an object back and hopefully use arryCustomers(0).firstName to strip the information out.

Which would be the most ideal situation, but no one has tried and the software I am working with is a good 15 years old and has been touched by a good few people so coding isnt really consistent.

I guess what I want to know is: Is this possible the way I have suggested or is there a way that will work?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Write the code, and I am sure it will work

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to ask. Are you asking if VB6 supports [object arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa262139%28v%3dvs.60%29)?

Comment: Yes, the way you proposed is possible, and it _is_ the proper way. Simply create the array and start using it. What's stopping you from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can absolutely do this.

```
Dim arryCustomers() As Customers ' Declare an array of customers
ReDim Preserve arryCustomers(20) ' Dynamically change the size of the array

' Create an instance of a customer and populate the members
Dim Customer0 As New Customers
Set Customer0 = New Customers
With Customer0
    .firstName = "Bob"
    .lastName = "Roberton"
End With

Set arryCustomers(0) = Customer0 ' Set the first element of the array

Debug.Print arryCustomers(0).firstName ' Returns "Bob"
```